# txZMQ upgrade from 0.7.0 to 0.7.3 => exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, twisted, zeromq

The following code works with txZMQ 0.7.0, but breaks as follow on txZMQ 0.7.3. What's the problem? Is this a bug in txZMQ.

Here is the test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from twisted.internet import reactor
from txzmq import ZmqEndpoint, ZmqFactory, ZmqPubConnection

import msgpack


zf = ZmqFactory()
e = ZmqEndpoint('bind', 'tcp://*:5557')

s = ZmqPubConnection(zf, e) 

def publish():
    data = [35, 11, 20, 4, 49, 1, 1, 49]
    msgpack_data = msgpack.packb(data)
    print "publishing %r" % data
    s.publish(msgpack_data)

reactor.callLater(1, publish)
reactor.run()
```

With the txZMQ 0.7.0:

```
pivert@pivert-desktop:~/tmp/twisted$ ./example.py 
publishing [35, 11, 20, 4, 49, 1, 1, 49]
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example.py", line 28, in <module>
    reactor.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1192, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "./example.py", line 24, in publish
    s.publish(msgpack_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/txzmq/pubsub.py", line 26, in publish
    self.send(tag + b'\0' + message)
exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Then, I downgrade txZMQ to 0.7.0:

```
root@pivert-desktop:~# pip install txZMQ==0.7.0
```

And re-execute:

```
pivert@pivert-desktop:~/tmp/twisted$ ./example.py 
publishing [35, 11, 20, 4, 49, 1, 1, 49]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue.

https://github.com/smira/txZMQ/issues/56

I worked around it by adding tag=b'' to my call to publish()

e.g:

```
s.publish(msgpack_data, tag=b'')
```